# Three orthogonal surfaces given by a coordinate system.

Tags: coordinate-systems

Given the following coordinate system:

$q_1=\frac{x^2-y^2}{2}$

$q_2=xy$

$q_3=z$

What kind of surfaces are given by $q_1$ constant, $q_2$ constant, and $q_3$ constant respectively?

I am pretty sure that these surfaces are not cilindrical hyperbolics, but something weirder.

By the way, the problem is with the variables $q_1$ and $q_2$. It is clear that if $q_3$ is constant then we have a plane.

These surfaces have a name?

Comment: take the plane $z=0$ and carefully draw, say, $q_1 = 0,$ $q_1= 1,$ $q_1 = -1.$ Similar for $q_2.$ Then think about it. http://www.printablepaper.net/category/graph

Comment: I don't get it. If I think that $q_1$ is constant then the following is a parametric equation:
$q_2=\pm y\sqrt{2q_1+y^2}$
$q_3=z$
But I don't know what kind of surfaces is this...